# Excel Workday not excluding Thanksgiving

Tags: excel

[image]

In 2002, Thanksgiving was on the 28th of November. So two working days before Monday, Dec 2nd should be Wednesday Nov 27th.

But

```
WORKDAY(A1,-2) Where the cell A1 has the value 12/2/2002 stored

gives me 11/28/2002
```

Is there a command or option that keeps track of the days financial markets are closed in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but [=WORKDAY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx) can be modified to take account of days to exclude to suit.

Syntax is `WORKDAY(start_date,days,holidays)`

> **Holidays** is an optional list of one or more dates to exclude from
>   the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating
>   holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contain the
>   dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the
>   dates.

Comment: Will I have to manually create this in a sheet (or array if using VBA) or does it already exist in Excel and I just need to call it?